# Solve $\lfloor x \rfloor ^2 + 9 \{x\}^2=6x-10, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $$\lfloor x \rfloor ^2 + 9 \{x\}^2=6x-10, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
I tried to:

$$\lfloor x \rfloor ^2 + 9 (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)^2=6x-10$$

$$ 18 x \lfloor x \rfloor -10 \lfloor x \rfloor^2=(3x-1)^2 +9 $$

but I got stuck from here, or I started the exercise wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Welp, I had written a solution for $9x^2$ instead of $9\{x\}^2$

Comment: @TheBestMagician I read your solution, and I realized I made a typo. I'm sorry

Comment: No problem, I have updated the solution with the new problem. The idea is similar

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$x\ge \lfloor x\rfloor>x-1$$
$$x^2\ge \lfloor x\rfloor ^2>x^2-2x+1$$
$$x^2+9>9\{x\}^2+\lfloor x\rfloor^2>x^2-2x+1$$
$$x^2+9>6x-10>x^2-2x+1$$
$$4+\sqrt5\approx 6.2>x>4-\sqrt5\approx 1.7$$
Hence $\lfloor x\rfloor\in\{2,3,4,5,6\}$. Now do casework based on each value of $\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Comment: I didn't think it would work using $x \geq \lfloor x \rfloor > x-1$ and I didn't try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Writing $x=\{x\}+\lfloor x\rfloor,$ you can re-arrange your equation to get:

$$(\lfloor x\rfloor -3)^2+1=6\{x\}-9\{x\}^2.$$

The function $f(u)=6u-9u^2$ has a maximum at $f(1/3)=1,$ so the right side is at most $1.$ The left side is at least $1.$

I’ll leave the last step to you.